# Is there a site which offers an interactive F# shell?

Tags: f#, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a site like [try ruby](http://tryruby.sophrinix.com/) that allows one to experiment in an F# interactive shell?  I'd like to try a few commands without installing Visual Studio or Mono.

Comment: I'd love to see this happen too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not yet that I know of.  (This is something the F# team would love to do if/when we can find the free time to put it together.)

(Note that you don't need VS or Mono - you can just have .Net and then install the F# CTP and just get the runtime, command-line compiler, and fsi.exe, and use that.  But it would be nicer if there were a no-install web-site-visit try-it thingy.)

Comment: I have been working on something like this, but don't have anything to show for it yet.

Answer (score 10):

There is also now [tryfs.net](http://tryfs.net/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/) for experiments with OCaml. The core of F# and OCaml is similar, just remember not to use light version of syntax, advanced F# features and .net libraries :)

Comment: Thanks for the codepad.org link.  Unfortunately, even for the most basic F# programs, there are syntax difference that prevent them from working in OCaml.  For example, [1..10] works in F#, but in OCaml one needs to define a range function.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you may use ocaml with syntax expensions (not at codepad) and you will get nice resalts. F.e. see pa_monad to beautify monadic expressions.

Answer (score 3):

[ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/) now supports F# ! [Here are some samples](http://www.ideone.com/recent/124-fs).

It's not really a REPL, but rather an online compiler.